# SQL join 2 tables: T1 column with WHERE and T2 column with SUM

Tags: mysql

**Scenario**: I got 3 tables

ITEM: item_id, name

STOCK: item_id, stock_quantity, location_id

COUNT: item_id, counting_quantity, timestamp

I want a table:

REPORT: item_id, name, stock_quantity (at location_id = '1'), SUM of counting_quantity

How can i achieve this? Thank you very much.

**Explanation**: Monthly i count stocks at warehouse 1 (location_id = 1).
I got first 2 tables
So i create 3rd table and use a barcode scanner to insert a row.
Then create the 4th table to watch the difference between stock_quantity and counting quantity while scanning/counting/inserting a record.
After counting, i export table REPORT and truncate table COUNT for next month counting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve this with two `JOIN`s and a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  `item`.`item_id`,
  `item`.`name`,
  SUM(`stock`.`stock_quantity`) AS 'stock_quantity',
  SUM(`count`.`counting_quantity`) AS 'counting_quantity'
FROM `item`
INNER JOIN `stock` ON `item`.`item_id` = `stock`.`item_id`
LEFT JOIN `count` ON `item`.`item_id` = `count`.`item_id`
WHERE `stock`.`location_id` = 1
GROUP BY `item`.`item_id`, `item`.`name`
```